# How can I use Visual Studio code to incorporate the SFML library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'd want to use this library in a C++ project I'm working on, but I'm getting the following error:
SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory

Please help me with a bit simpler solution, if possible. Since I'm very new to all this.

Comment: CMake springs to mind. Worth the google-fu.

Comment: Please be more specific. How was your project created? Have you used Makefiles, CMake or a build system? Are you using Visual Studio (the IDE) or Visual Studio Code (the editor)? Have you followed the tutorial in SFML site (https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are various method you let your compiler know where is the file,  you can do :

```
#include <include/SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

but some compilers are different and may or may not have files, or just store them differently .
I am pretty sure the issue will be resolved.

and also you can give path to the file when you execute the file just put a -I flag :

```
-I/path/to/SFML/headers
```